# Javascript Regex One Decimal

Tags: javascript, html

......... Javascript function

```
  function isNumberKey(evt)
       {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;

          return true;
       }
```

this works well with numbers but for decimal it allows multiple decimals. i just want one decimal. thanks in advance

Comment: This question is not related to PHP. Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post RELEVANT HTML and Script to give us a [mcve]. Also please elaborate on what you mean by recall

Comment: you are passing in strings to the function so they need to be quoted. Are you not getting errors? Also, you are targeting an element of ID `demo` ~ so each time this is called will overwrite previous invocations output - thus displaying only the last one most likely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use data-attributes here

Change date-start and date-end with $Ldate  and $Bdate

But we need today's date somewhere no?

```js
var x = setInterval(function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".date")].forEach(el => {
    var diff = new Date(el.getAttribute("date-end")).getTime() - new Date().getTime(); // or date-end?
  
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    el.innerHTML = diff < 0 ? "EXPIRED" : days + "d " + hours + "h " +
      minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  })
}, 1000);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='center'><i class='fa fa-database fa-3x' aria-hidden='true'></i>Server row 1</td>
      <td><i class='fa fa-line-chart fa-3x'></i>Profit row 1</td>
      <td><i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'></i><span class="date" date-start="2019-11-13 10:00:00" date-end="2020-01-01 10:00:00"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='center'><i class='fa fa-database fa-3x' aria-hidden='true'></i>Server row 2</td>
      <td><i class='fa fa-line-chart fa-3x'></i>Profit row 2</td>
      <td><i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'></i><span class="date" date-start="2019-11-11 10:00:00" date-end="2019-12-01 10:00:00"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: its working but i want the date comes from sql server. which is $Ldate = $row['LastDate']; $Bdate = $row['DateBought']; this. tell me how to pass it

Comment: As I said, echo it in the data-start and -end - you can see the date format I use, you can use another bit I need to see it

Comment: Just add my spans to your html

Answer (score 0):

I made an assumption that the display for the countdown should be associated to the row in the HTML table that is being rendered so if you assign a `dataset` attibute that refers to the element to be used as output one can easily target it via javascript. By assigning an attribute that combines the two relevant dates you can fudge around with those to set the start/end dates within the function body - assigned after the loop for convenience here.

```
<?php

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($WltQRslt)){
        $Ldate = $row['LastDate'];
        $Bdate = $row['DateBought'];
        $id=sprintf('%s_%s',$Ldate,$Bdate);

        echo "
        <tr>
            <td class='center'>
                <i class='fa fa-database fa-3x' aria-hidden='true'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row['Server']}
            </td>
            <td>
                <i class='fa fa-line-chart fa-3x'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row['Profit']}
            </td>
            <td>
            <i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <div class='countdown' data-id='{$id}'></div>
            </td>
        </tr>";
    }

?>

<script>
    const countdown=function( id ){
        const INTERVAL=1000;
        const difference=function(n){
            let d=Math.floor( n / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) );
            let h=Math.floor( ( n % ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) ) / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 ) );
            let m=Math.floor( ( n % ( 1000 * 60 * 60 ) ) / ( 1000 * 60 ) );
            let s=Math.floor( ( n % ( 1000 * 60 ) ) / 1000 );
            return d + "d " + h + "h " + m + "m " + s + "s";
        };

        let ldate=new Date( id.split('_')[0] ).getTime();
        let bdate=new Date( id.split('_')[1] ).getTime();

        let tx=setInterval( ()=>{
            bdate -= INTERVAL;
            let distance=ldate - bdate;

            let node=document.querySelector( 'div[ data-id="'+id+'" ]' );
                node.textContent=difference( distance );

            if( distance < 0 ){
                clearInterval( tx );
                node.textContent='EXPIRED';
            }
        },INTERVAL );
    }


    Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('div.countdown') ).forEach( div=>{
        countdown( div.dataset.id )
    });
</script>
```